# Mouse to drag-and-scroll element with iPhone/Android effect

Tags: javascript, scroll

Hard to explain in a subject, I know... so I will help with a video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rcPIvGRwrxA

Skip to 00:12 and you get the idea. I would like to be able to click with the mouse, drag (left/right or up/down) and "pull" the element (can be text, an image, any kind of div, ...) with that kind of physical "slowing down" effect.

I tried with some "major" Javascript frameworks (Scriptaculous, JQuery, etc...) but I did not find any good way to achieve a similar effect.

Do you have any good tip so I can get a similar example to work with?

Comment: This one is great http://www.azoffdesign.com/plugins/js/overscroll but wont work on IE8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This JQuery plugin might be interesting for you: http://www.ajaxupdates.com/an-iphone-scrolling-plugin-for-jquery/

Comment: First thing: I love you, please tell me where I can send you some money. Second thing: how could I miss it? I've already configured and tested it and it seems to work. it's not THAT smooth sometimes but the overall idea was perfectly achieved.

Comment: I had to reopen this question due to a total incompatibility with Internet Explorer 8 (sadly). Sigh.